# spaCy loading model fails

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am trying to load spaCy model `de_core_news_sm` without any success. Since our company police seems to block the `python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm` prompt command, I downloaded the model manually and used pip install on the local tar.gz archive, which worked out well.

However, calling `nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")` in my code throws the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
[E149] Error deserializing model. Check that the config used to create the 
component matches the model being loaded.
  File "pipes.pyx", line 642, in 
spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger.from_disk.load_model
```

I have no idea how to deal with this. Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `python -m spacy validate` to check whether the model you downloaded is compatible with the version of spacy you have installed. This kind of error happens when the versions aren't compatible. (Probably one is v2.1 and the other is v2.2.)

Comment: You've spotted the issue correctly. I have been using model version 2.2.1 with spaCy 2.2.2. The latest compatible model version is 2.2.0. After changing the model version my code runs smoothely.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge.